# C# Error when Insert Data To Database

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I want to insert data into a `.MDB` file, but I get this error:

[image: Error]

This is my `.MDB` table :

[image: My Database]

This my code :

```
private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string sql = string.Format("insert into Input (Tgl, p, l, t, Shift, Grup, Good Board, Reject Board, Wood, Emulsion, Glue, NH4CL, Urea, Rambung, Meranti, Veneer, Potongan, Lamtoro, Log End, Saw Dust, Sembarang, MDF Screen Dust, Kemiri, Slab Durian, Flakes) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}','{12}','{13}','{14}','{15}','{16}','{17}','{18}','{19}','{20}','{21}','{22}','{23}','{24}')", dateTimePicker1.Text, txt_p.Text, txt_l.Text, txt_t.Text, txt_Shift, txt_Group, txt_GoodBoard.Text, txt_RejectBoard.Text, txt_Wood.Text, txt_Emulsi.Text, txt_Glue.Text, txt_NH4CL.Text, txt_Urea.Text, txt_Rambung.Text, txt_Meranti.Text, txt_Veneer.Text, txt_Potongan.Text, txt_Lamtoro.Text, txt_LogEnd.Text, txt_SawDust.Text, txt_Sembarang.Text, txt_MDFScreenDust.Text, txt_Kemiri.Text, txt_SlabDurian.Text, txt_Flakes.Text);

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(koneksi);
        conn.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Page 1");
    }
    catch (OleDbException salah)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(salah.ToString());
    }
}
```

When I insert 3 columns, it works, but when I want to insert many columns, the code does not work.

I have no idea what could be wrong with my statement. I already searched many questions similar, but still have no idea what's wrong with me code. Can anybody help me solve this problem? Or does anyone have suggestions for fixing my code? This is my 1st time I use a `.MDB` database file.

Thanks

Comment: looks like u missed `.Text` here .. `txt_Shift, txt_Group`

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `insert into Input ...` to `INSERT INTO [Input] ...`

Comment: SQL is not case sensitive

Comment: @Yousaf yes, notice the `[Input]` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is the reserved word 'input' should rename it.
[ODBC Reserved Keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) Just to clarify the previous answer.